# Why parameter returns 'undefined' when using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js

I'm starting to use vuetify along with a 'payment gateway' that I'm learning, but I've had a little problem.

If I have a form like this:

```js
<form @submit.prevent="continuar" id="customer-form">
    <div class="card-errors"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre del usuario de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" data-epayco="card[name]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" data-epayco="card[email]">
    </div>
      ...
    <button type="submit">¡Pagar ahora!</button>
</form>
```

The "Token" parameter returns a value that is not undefined.

```js
continuar(event){

  ePayco.token.create(event.target, (error, token) => {
    if(!error) {
      console.log("token: " + token)
    } else {
      console.log(error)
    }
   })
},
```

But when I use vuetify the "Token" parameter returns "undefined" even when the "Epayco" library shows a message that everything has happened correctly.

```js
  <form id="customer-form" @submit.prevent="continuar">
    <div class="card-errors"></div>
    <v-layout row align-center>
      <v-flex md3 offset-md1 class="mr-3">
          <v-layout justify-end>
              <span>Nombre en la tarjeta*</span>
           </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex md4>
        <v-text-field data-epayco="card[name]"/>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row align-center>
        <v-flex md3 offset-md1 class="mr-3">
            <v-layout justify-end>
                <span>Email</span>
            </v-layout>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex md4>
          <v-text-field data-epayco="card[email]"/>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    ......
    <v-layout class="my-3" justify-center>
      <v-btn type="submit">Pagar</v-btn>
    </v-layout>
</form>
```

Does anyone know why the problem?

It should be noted that when an error occurs the parameter 'error' returns the error and not undefined

Answer (score 0):

According to the example [here](https://github.com/epayco/epayco-node) it appears you should be using the `ePayco.token.create()` function a bit differently.

```
epayco.token.create(paymentDetails)
.then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err: " + err);
});
```

Comment: According to the official documentation, this is done, but on the server, in the client (according to the documentation), it is done in the manner in which I attached it in the post. The problem is in the "v-text-field"; If I put in place of "<v-text-field />" a simple "<input>" works correctly.